# Keeping track of change in a CoreData entity

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a simple iOS application that make use of `CoreData`.
For a particular reason I need to display an history records in a `UITableView` based on Entity values.

I explain better, supposing I have entity A with field of value x, then at a given date I changed value of A with xy.

In `UITableView`, I expect to see two records, grouped by date of change.

```
25/07/2011
A=x
28/07/2011 
A=xy
```

I am still thinking with SQL in mind, which is obviously wrong regarding `CoreData`, so the first solution coming to my mind would be to add a new entity maybe with a relationship to A.
So I wonder what's the best `CoreData` approach for this, maybe there's a convenient mechanism to save and recall a snapshot of an entity or a specific attribute at a given datetime.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive this with `KVO (Key Value Observing)`. Every NSManagedObject subclass can override:

`- (BOOL)validateValue:(id *)value forKey:(NSString *)key error:(NSError **)error`

You can override these as well, but not encouraged to:

`- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key` or

`- (void)willChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key`

methods, which gets call every time the value gets changed for a particular keypath. I belive this will solve your problem. Take a look at KVO Programming Guide to get a more deep understanding of KVO subject @ http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html .

Comment: thanks, the real problem is how and where to store those changes.

Comment: You can add an attribute to an Entity, which will be a transformable and store an NSArray of previous entries and update it each time the value of an attribute changes. Or you can add another Entity with relationship to the previuos one if you want more detailed information stored, such as timestamp of the change.